# what is the meaning "using std : : setw; includes scope resolution operator

Tags: c++, c++11

```
using std::setw;
```

What does this mean in C++?? When it is used in programming? Explain what includes the scope resolution operator.

Comment: `::` is the scope resolution operator.

Answer (score 3):

It brings `std::setw;` into scope.

```
using std::setw;
// setw can now be used without qualifying it with std::
```

Beware of ADL when (accidentally) applying unqualified `setw` to a value of a user-defined type.

Answer (score 1):

`setw` is defined in the namespace `std` as in

```
namespace std{
  void setw(int) {..}
};
```

if you want to use it you either use `std::` prefix or include the namespace into your project like this

```
using namespace std;
```

the latter is not great as it may cause naming collisions with your code

**edit:** or as @rightfold mentioned

Comment: +1 for the evilness of using namespace std;